# Where to Start with SDK Android

Tags: android, sdk

So I just downloaded the Android SDK App Development Software and would like to know where to start. I have NO experience in programing in anything *but* Delphi7. I dont mind if you just give me a website.
Thank you!

Comment: Here you go: http://developer.android.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question is gonna earn you a lot of negative votes. There are tons of stuff for starters just use google and this forum.

You need to have a basic knowledge of java. for android i would recommend `the new boston` series on youtube, for book 'Android 4 application development` and for online reference [developers.android.com](http://developer.android.com).

Comment: that wasn't me... thanks dor the tip! just what iwas looking for

Comment: @DNgentle sometimes i just dn't understand this forum. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @RohanKandwal: For the record: the down-vote was not from me either, but my guess is that it's because you bothered to give an answer to this question that is so obvious to be off-topic. Note that the other answer here also has a down-vote... Answering off-topic questions give others a reason to ask off-topic questions because they get answered anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Go through training on android web site: 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

First IDE of choise should be Eclipse.

Comment: Why Eclipse? It's awful

Comment: Seriously, Eclipse is terrible. I still prefer developing in Visual Studio, but IntelliJ IDEA is way the frack better than Eclipse in every way.

Comment: Im currently using Eclips... it depends on user preference, I use a lot of software that people don't normally recomend and it works. Don't discredit software unless it has a score of 4 out of 10 or less.